# While swaping to next page in viewpager the html video loads from server but the previous html video does not get stopped

Tags: android

While swaping to next page in viewpager the html video loads from server but the previous html video does not get stopped. how  to stop/pause webview video
anyone answer me, thanks

Comment: Pass the viewPager object to your fragment and stop the player if view pager state change .

Comment: Please post your code. Its really hard to figure out what is going on right now